# CanCan Ability in Rails - Giving partial manage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancan

I have three roles of AdminUsers:

- admin
- editor
- student

I need the editor to have the ability to manage(add/view/delete) AdminUser accounts that its role is student.Yet, he can't see whose role is admin or editor.

With the following code, he could view only without creation/deletion/edit

```
      if user.role?(:admin)
        can :manage, :all
      elsif user.role?(:editor)
        can :read, ActiveAdmin::Page, :name => "Dashboard"
        can :manage, :all
        cannot :manage, AdminUser
        can :manage, AdminUser, :role => :student

      else
        can :read, :all
      end
```

Comment: You were actually quite close: you should have specified `:role => :student` instead of `:role => :editor` because you're constraining the the target of the operation, not the subject (which has already been constrained with your `elsif user.role?(:editor)`. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're saying that a user who is an editor should be able to manage the account of another user who is a student. If that's the case, this should work:

```
  if user.role?(:admin)
    can :manage, :all
  elsif user.role?(:editor)
    can :read, ActiveAdmin::Page, :name => "Dashboard"
    can :manage, AdminUser, :role => :student
  else
    can :read, :all
  end
```

Comment: I get this error "The accessible_by call cannot be used with a block 'can' definition."

Comment: Please show the code that is generating the error (probably in your controller).

Comment: I don't have a controller for ActiveAdmin::Page, the page that causes erorr, is the page that lists users. It uses index method.

Comment: Okay, I modified the solution above. Please try it and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It's not working as expected, it shows the whole list of AdminUser I have and gave the editor a full ability.

Comment: Oh, I needed to add "cannot :manage, AdminUser" before the can manage Admin User line to view students only.

I got another issue now, I can't create new AdminUser. Do you know how to be able to create it as long as I will create student?

Comment: Please start another question for that -- it's a different problem.

Comment: Also: it's just a matter of taste, but writing `can :manage, :all` and then subtracting specific abilities strikes me as strange and error-prone. I only use `can :manage, :all` for a real admin, a god-like user that can do anything. For other roles (like `editor`), I add specific abilities as required.